# Taking screenshot directly to clipboard

Tags: macos, screen-capture

99% of the time when I take a screenshot (using <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> to draw a rectangle on screen) I would like to directly paste it somewhere (Slack, PowerPoint, etc). Unfortunately, on my machine, I *first* have to click the little popup to bring the screenshot into a proper window for me to be able to copy/paste it.

Is there a convenient way to copy the screenshot into the buffer of my machine directly? I don't care about saving the screenshot on my disk (which it seems to do be default...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hold <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd> when doing a screenshot. It will be saved in clipboard instead of saving an image to chosen folder (no thumbnail in bottom right corner will be shown as well).

Comment: This is so convenient! Thank you!